# How to address data from Local Storage to user_id and SessionId, and if that is even possible?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have data in html from ispring, and this is interactive menu. I observe that i have local storage (clearly last viewed page). I have also system of logging and i need save that local storage in user_id or sessionid. I find this: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-get-localstorage-key-value-into-a-php-variable-If-so-how-can-we-do-it

I tried this:

in window.location maybe i need do something, and I don't know if I am going in the right direction

I have also another code in indexmenu.html:

I am a beginner in programming, and I going like blind in the forest, please help me

```
  <script>
  var value = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
 jQuery.post("indexmenu.html", {myKey: value}, function(data)
  {
  window.location.href='http://smartangielski.cba.pl/indexmenu/';
  });
   </script>
   <?php if(isset($_POST["user_id"])) { $value = $_POST['myKey']; }?>
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''

I need after logged in page, get local storage data from last logged activity

Comment: Very hard to understand what you actually want here, resp. what your problem is. Please go read [ask], and try to be a bit more specific about what your actual issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax to send JS data to a PHP page. Use the below coed for reference:

```
  //include jquery library too

  var myData = localStorage.getItem('myKey');

  $.ajax({ 
  url: 'http://smartangielski.cba.pl/indexmenu/', // URL of the PHP page where you want to send the variable
  type: 'POST',
  data: {myValue: myData },
  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful
    //Do something
  },
  error: function(e) {
    //called when there is an error
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

In the PHP page, you can access the data using:

```
$myVal = $_POST['myValue'];
```

You can read more [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494)

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility to send from ajax to indexmenu.html, couse there is only way with that page in html, can i just paste php code as a part of html? I try this, and i dont know which function i should use in the field: "do something"